# How to fill out ignored Field to store query calculation result

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using go-gorm

this is my model struct

```
type Inventory struct {
   ID         int `gorm:"primaryKey;notNull"  json:"id"`
   Qty        uint `json:"qty"`
   In         *int `gorm:"-:all"`
   Out        *int `gorm:"-:all"`
}
```

Notice `In` and `Out` Fields, I dont want *Gorm* to create these fields in database when running migration, so I give `-:all` tags,  but I want these fields to be filled out by calculation value like this:

```
"IFNULL(SUM(IF(qty > 0, qty, 0)),0) AS in"
```

and

```
"IFNULL(SUM(IF(qty < 0, qty, 0)),0) AS out"
```

Unfortunately because this tag `-:all` *Gorm* wont fill out those two fields therefore its value always nil (the default value)

my question is how to instruct *Gorm* to not perform create/update/select/migration but fill those fields if there are values for them?

For now my solution is to use this tag `<-:false`, allowing *Gorm* to migrate (create) those columns in inventories table but never **write** nor **update** them (their value always null), this way Gorm will perform **select query** to these column and fill out the struct fields if there are values, but those columns are useless in database perspective

edit

Qty is uint type

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine some [Fields Tags](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Fields-Tags)  `<-:false` *no write permission* and `-:migration` *not migrated permission*, for example:

```
type Inventory struct {
    ID  int  `gorm:"primaryKey;notNull"  json:"id"`
    Qty uint `json:"qty"`
    In  *int `gorm:"<-:false;-:migration"`
    Out *int `gorm:"<-:false;-:migration"`
}
```

```golang
var res Inventory
err := db.Select(`*, 4 as in, 3 as out`).First(&res).Error
```

[image]

Comment: This indeed solves "useless column" problem, but will raise other problem when .Joins("Inventory"), gorm will create select for columns inventories.in and inventories.out but those columns don't exist in database

Comment: @Bens - add a code snippet, please)